# Ошибка при отправки формы PHP?

Tags: php

Так вот есть код вроде правильный, но всё рано пишет ошибку, собственно вот код:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'blueIzek';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo $name = ($_POST["name"]);
    echo $password = ($_POST["password"]);
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO inquiries(name, password) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $password]);

header("Location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

А вот ошибка

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 
Table 'blueizek.inquiries' doesn't exist in C:\laragon\www\BlueIzek\registHook.php:22 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\laragon\www\BlueIzek\registHook.php(22): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO inq...') 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\BlueIzek\registHook.php on line 22`
```

Строчка номер 22 это `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);`

Если я как-то поле настроил неправильно то вот есть фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Название таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи название таблицы и бд в phpmyadmin

Comment: Исправил вопрос, смотрте внизу.

Comment: inquiries != sistem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблица называется sistem, а Вы вставляете в inquiries.
Попробуйте так: `INSERT INTO sistem(name, password) VALUES (?, ?)`

Comment: А я всё вспомнил и понял спасибо!

Comment: @ДанилГончаренко а галочку поставить?:)